# How do I position eBay product images underneath each other with spacing in between each image

Tags: html, image

I found the following code online:

```
<center><table>
<tr>
<td><a href="" http:="" imageshack.us="" photo="" my-images="" 838="" tmp423.jpg=""   '=""><img src="http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/7602/tmp423.jpg" width="300" height="300"></a>
</td>
<td><a href="" http:="" imageshack.us="" photo="" my-images="" 402="" dsc1324o.jpg="" '=""><img src="http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/7982/dsc1324o.jpg" width="300" height="300"></a>
</td>
<td><a href="" http:="" imageshack.us="" photo="" my-images="" 338="" dsc1325v.jpg="" '=""><img src="http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/135/dsc1325v.jpg" width="300" height="300"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table></center>
```

to position images side by side each other with spacing in between each image. I am trying to position each image underneath each other with spacing in between each image in eBay listing description. What's the html code to position each image underneath each other with spacing in between each image? What do I need to change or add to the above code to get the images centered and positioned underneath each other with spacing in between each images? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have everything in one table row (`<tr></tr>`), this is why everything is showing up horizontally. The easiest way without CSS to get this vertically is to put each image in a table row. Also, whatever `'=""` is, it's throwing the HTML sytax off; fix it or get rid of it. As it is now, it's not doing anything. Lastly, you are not closing your image tags.

Try this:

```
<center><table>
<tr>
    <td><a href="" http:="" imageshack.us="" photo="" my-images=""        838="" tmp423.jpg=""><img src="http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/7602/tmp423.jpg" width="300"  height="300"></img></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="" http:="" imageshack.us="" photo="" my-images="" 402="" dsc1324o.jpg=""><img src="http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/7982/dsc1324o.jpg" width="300" height="300"></img></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="" http:="" imageshack.us="" photo="" my-images="" 338="" dsc1325v.jpg=""><img src="http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/135/dsc1325v.jpg" width="300" height="300"></img></a></td>
</tr>
</table></center>
```